# Spring MVC webapp rebuilds both views when opening new browser session

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a java spring mvc webapp that builds a table of statuses making ajax calls to update ping status every 3 seconds and performance/health status every 5 min. It works correctly but the only thing is I added spring security and whenever a second user logs in from a different page it resets both views instead of just building the new view. How do I make it so each new user session has their own view to update without affecting the other open browser sessions?

Here's my jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Site Connector</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pages/styles/main.css">
<link rel="colorSchemeMapping" href="pages/styles/colorschememapping.xml">
<script type="text/javascript" src="pages/scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function updateReachability() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'updatePing',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#site').html(data);
        }
    });
}

function updateStatus() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'updateStatus',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#site').html(data);
        }
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    updateStatus();
    setInterval(updateStatus, 300000);
    setInterval(updateReachability, 3000);
    }, false);

</script>

</head>

<body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple style='tab-interval:.5in'>

<div id="site">
<div id="upper_left">          
                <img src="pages/sickLogo.gif" alt="SICK Inc. logo"/>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
</div>
<div id="upper_right">
    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
        <c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/logout"/>
        <form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post" id="logoutForm">
            Logged in as: ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} <input type="submit" value="logout" />
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
        </form>
    </c:if>
</div>

<h1>Site Connector</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>IP Address</th>
        <th>Facility Name</th>
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>Health Status</th>
        <th>Performance Status</th>
    </tr>

    <c:forEach items="${site.hubs}" var="hub">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="${hub.pingStatus}">${hub.ipAddress}</td>
        <td>${hub.siteName}</td>
        <td><a href="${hub.url}" target="_blank">${hub.url}</a></td>
        <td bgcolor="${hub.healthStatus}"></td>
        <td bgcolor="${hub.performanceStatus}"></td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here's my controller class:

```
@Controller
public class SiteController {

private static final Logger logger =     Logger.getLogger(SiteController.class.getName());

private static String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");

private SiteManager manager = new SiteManager();

private SiteStatus site = new SiteStatus();

private ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("SiteConnectorPage");

private boolean checkPing = true;

//method to run on initialization to build site list table from file
@RequestMapping("/connector")
public ModelAndView init() {

    System.out.println("Connector method called");

    //call method to create the list of error codes to search for
    try
    {
        if(osName.matches("^.*Windows.*$"))
        {
            //change file location to C:/SVP/hub-connector/site-list/SiteList.csv
            site = manager.buildSiteStatus("C:/p4_dominer/SiteConnector/SiteList.csv", site);
            //set the ping status and URL's for each hub
            if(!site.getHubs().isEmpty())
            {
                //set URL's for each hub and determines their reachability status
                manager.buildURL(site.getHubs(), true);
            }
            else
            {
                logger.error("Site List is empty, please check contents of input file");//throw empty list exception
            }
        }
        else //path to Linux location
        {
            site = manager.buildSiteStatus("/home/engineering/SVP/site-connector/site-list/SiteList.csv", site);

            if(!site.getHubs().isEmpty())
            {
            //set URL's for each hub and determines their reachability status
            manager.buildURL(site.getHubs(), false);
            }
            else
            {
                logger.error("Site List is empty, please check contents of input file");//throw empty list exception
            }
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    model.addObject("site", site);
    return model;
}


//method to update ping status
@RequestMapping(value = "/updatePing", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView updatePingStatus()
{
    if(checkPing) {
        try
        {
            if(osName.matches("^.*Windows.*$"))
            {
                System.out.println("updatePing method called");
                //set URL's for each hub and determines their reachability status
                manager.buildURL(site.getHubs(), true);
            }
            else
            {
                //set URL's for each hub and determines their reachability status
                manager.buildURL(site.getHubs(), false);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return model;

}

@RequestMapping(value="/customLogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loginPage(@RequestParam(value="error", required=false) String error,
                              @RequestParam(value="logout", required=false) String logout)
{
    ModelAndView loginModel = new ModelAndView("customLogin");

    if(error != null) {
        loginModel.addObject("error", "Login was unsuccessful, Please Try Again.");
    }
    if(logout != null) {
        loginModel.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
    }

    return loginModel;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/updateStatus", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView updateStatus()
{
    System.out.println("updateStatus method called");
    //set checkPing to false so updatePingStatus method doesn't update model concurrentlly which was causing the table to flash
    checkPing = false;
    if(osName.matches("^.*Windows.*$"))
    {

        /*test code */long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        manager.getStatusData(site.getHubs(), site.getDeviceErrors(), true);
        /*test code */long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        /*test code */long duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000;
        /*test code*/logger.info("updateStatus took " + duration + " ms");
    }
    else
    {
        manager.getStatusData(site.getHubs(), site.getDeviceErrors(), false);
    }
    checkPing = true;

    return model;
}

}
```

Here's my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"   xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>connector</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>connector</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/connector-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>customLogin.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And here's my servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.sick.controller" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/pages/**" location="/pages/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<beans:bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<http pattern="/pages/**" security="none"/>

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/customLogin*" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/customLogin?logout" />
    <form-login login-page="/customLogin" authentication-failure-url="/customLogin?error" default-target-url="/connector" />
    <session-management><concurrency-control max-sessions="10" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/></session-management>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: I don't see which endpoint is causing the issue, but try to move those non-static global variables to method level.

Comment: Thanks Dino Tw I changed the manager and model global variables to method level and it sort of works. I think what I have left to figure out is I put the SiteStatus object which contains the table data as a requestParam in my two update methods but have to try to figure out how to pass that object back to my controller from my ajax methods in my jsp. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Since the content of table is dynamically rendered, the easiest way I can think of is to construct JSON object on the client side and send it over to server. jQuery.ajax() can do that, too. And for content update, by RESTful convention, it's PUT method.

Answer (score 0):

Finally came up with the answer after a lot of googling. I added sessioning to my controller class so that each client request was updating its own session object and not affecting other open browsers.

```
@RequestMapping("/connector")
public ModelAndView init(HttpServletRequest request) {

    SiteManager manager = new SiteManager();
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("SiteConnectorPage");
    SiteStatus siteStatus = new SiteStatus();
    //create session if one doesn't exist
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

    System.out.println("Connector method called");

    try
    {
        if(osName.matches("^.*Windows.*$"))
        {
            siteStatus = manager.buildSiteStatus("C:/SICK/Site Connector/SiteList.csv");

            //set the ping status and URL's for each hub
            if(!siteStatus.getHubs().isEmpty())
            {
                //set URL's for each hub and determines their reachability status
                manager.buildURL(siteStatus.getHubs(), true);
            }
            else
            {
                logger.error("Site List is empty, please check contents of input file");//throw empty list exception
            }
        }
        else //path to Linux location
        {
            siteStatus = manager.buildSiteStatus("/home/engineering/SVP/site-connector/site-list/SiteList.csv");

            if(!siteStatus.getHubs().isEmpty())
            {
                //set URL's for each hub and determines their reachability status
                manager.buildURL(siteStatus.getHubs(), false);
            }
            else
            {
                logger.error("Site List is empty, please check contents of input file");//throw empty list exception
            }
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }

    session.setAttribute("site", siteStatus);
    model.addObject("site", siteStatus);
    return model;
}
```